# Creating A retest Indicator using pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Hi All I am trying to create a retest indicator using pine script
The code is below

```
//@version=5
indicator("Retest Indicator", overlay=true)


openBarCurrent = open [0]
closeBarCurrent = close [0]

PRICE = 1.24691
CurrencyPair_price = input.float(defval=0, title='GBPUSD')
PRICE := syminfo.ticker == "GBPUSD" ? CurrencyPair_price : PRICE
plot(PRICE)


Search_Back=10

if closeBarCurrent>PRICE
    Search_Back:=0

else
    Retested = false

while Search_Back<=10
    Search_Back+=1
    if (low[Search_Back]<PRICE) and (open[Search_Back+1]>PRICE)
        Retested := true

Up_retest = Retested == true ? color.black : na
barcolor(color = Up_retest,show_last = Search_Back)
```

[In the image attached this is basically what i want the code to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qXW6.png)

As shown in the image above I tried to write the code to output what would be in the image however it could not compile the code

As Search_back is a variable integer rather than a constant integer, therefore
Show_last = Search_Back' is not executable therefore is there away around this?

Comment: way aroung for historical bars looks like this: `barcolor(last_bar_index - bar_index < Search_Back ? Up_retest : na)`